# Unicode characters in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, unicode

So basically I have use an Api with unicode characters in my angular project .
For example &quot and &#039
I tried to use pipes to decode them but there are lots of them . Is there any library or any other way to decode them ?

here is a code if my pipe if it will be helpfull:

```
 transform(value: string) {
    let finalValue = value;
    if (finalValue.includes("&quot;") || finalValue.includes('&ldquo;')) {
      finalValue = finalValue.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
      finalValue = finalValue.replace(/&ldquo;/g, '"');
    }
    if (finalValue.includes("&#039;") || finalValue.includes('&rsquo;')) {
      finalValue = finalValue.replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
      finalValue = finalValue.replace(/&rsquo;/g, "'");
    }
    if (finalValue.includes("&amp;")) {
      finalValue = finalValue.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
    }


    return finalValue;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: not I tried with unescape but the result is the same